# Adding different listview in single fragment

Tags: android, listview, gridview, android-fragments

Hi in my current project I need to create one particular design for tablet. First let me tell you about the design. I need to create a activity in which three fragment should be there in that

1) First Fragment -> It should contain a GridView - Single colomn.

2) Second Fragment -> If user click the image in the grid view it should generate the custom list view in this second frament.

3) Third Fragment -> If user select the single list in previous second fragment it should show that list in this detail list view.

What I did is, I created one Activity and that xml is

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="3"
     tools:context="caresynchrony.sanvishealth.com.im026.ovn_tablet.SingleResident">
        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <GridView
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/gridViewHome"
            android:columnCount="1"
            android:columnWidth="250dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/selector_bt"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/listFragment"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1.2"/>
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/detailFragment"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1.3"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And the class file is,

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_single_resident);
    GridView gridview = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridViewHome);
    DashBoardAdaptor adapter = new DashBoardAdaptor(this);
    gridview.setAdapter(adapter);

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:

                    break;
                case 1:
                    Fragment fragment = new CareAlert();
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager =getSupportFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.listFragment, fragment);
                    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    //changeFragment(fragment,R.id.listFragment);
                    break;
```

And the second frament xml file is,

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="caresynchrony.sanvishealth.com.im026.ovn_tablet.CareAlert">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:weightSum="2">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="Recent Alerts"
    android:layout_weight=".2"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:background="@color/terms_text_color"
    android:textColor="@color/bt_text"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_gravity="left|top" />
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listViewCareList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1.8"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And the adapter file is

```
 if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       // v = minflater.inflate(R.layout.carerowlist,parent,false);
        v = inflater.inflate(row, parent,false);
        holder.name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewtype);
        holder.dob = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewdate);
        holder.msg = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewmsg);
        holder.priority = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewpriorityllevel);
        holder.priorityimage=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imageViewpriority);
        v.setTag(holder);
```

When I run my project I am getting these errors

```
Process: caresynchrony.sanvishealth.com.im026.ovn_tablet, PID: 2536
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:621)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:670)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:695)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:756)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
        at adapter.CareAlertAdapter.getView(CareAlertAdapter.java:60)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2263)
        at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1790)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:691)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:752)
        at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1616)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2091)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1660)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
```

**Note: Various design means, In for the first item in grid the list contain only 3 text view but for second and thirst item in grid it has 6 views. How can I achieve this.
Kindly comment below if you can't understand my question.**

Comment: If the functionality changes significantly in the 2nd fragment, and you are aware of how many different kinds of functionality there could be. You could create a fragment class for each type of functionality required. Then instance that fragment, instead of a single fragment. Otherwise, you are going to need to pass a condition into your fragment and set to a different adapter.

Comment: I did the same but I am getting binary error:  'android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class <unknown>
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:621)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:670)'

Comment: Explain what you have done in your question, and format your exception there. Show relevant code to your exception.

Comment: I added the code which I did. Kindly take a look.

Comment: It errors inflating your row:

v = inflater.inflate(row, parent,false);

What is "row"

Comment: row means resource id of the listview row layout.

Comment: Actually I extends ArrayAdapter while creating CustomAdapter for this listview So I need to pass the layout id as a parameter.  So the row is the name of the listview individual row layout.

Comment: The error is in the XML file, you need to provide the XML source for your row layout

Comment: Can u tell me what u r mentioning here "The XML Source"?????

Comment: If you are meaning this xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" I already added that...